# Ubuntu 14.04.2 can't login after update!

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, login

Hello Yesterday i installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 and all was going right i installed my gpu drivers too. Today the system asked me to do some updates and i gave the system the permission to download the updates and after the reboot the display is big and if i login with the correct password or with the guest session the screen goes black and it goes on the login screen again! I think that something happened with my gpu drivers, i don't know! Please help me if you can :)

Edit 1:If i press ctrl+alt+f1 i can login through the command line
Edit 2: I tried changing the permissions on my desktop but that did not help!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like you deinstalled your windowmanager. Log into the konsole and reinstall your windowmanager (apt-get install ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: It says that ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version :/

Comment: take a look at /var/log/Xorg.0.log look for errors or warnings

Comment: For some reason i can't see it can you guide me through the process sorry but i'm new with linux :(

Comment: Open the file in an editor (e.g. nano /var/log/Xorg.0.log) or use a pager (less /var/log/Xorg0.log). The error should be somewhere to the end of the file.  If it is an X11 component, it is prefixed with (EE).

Comment: There are a lot of errors most of them for the nvidia drivers should i write all of them here?

Comment: Best would be upload the file somewhere (e.g. http://pastebin.com/) if you are sure it is the nvidia-driver that is causing the error, you might also try to reinstall the nvidia-driver (apt-get install --reinstall )

Comment: There are like 6 or 7 errors 5 for nvidia so should i write them here?

Comment: It says that i don't have the latest nvidia driver what do i do know?